# Mistake with storing strings in char pointer array

Tags: c

I know this question might sound quite silly, but I somehow found myself stuck and need help. I have a `char*` variable `char* address="/a/asdasd/c/sdfsdf/adsd";` and I declared an array of char pointer `char* store[5];` . I'm trying to divide the content in the variable `address` by tracing the slash(`/`) and trying to store each part in the char pointer variable `store` by doing the following

```
char* store[5];
char* address="/a/asdasd/c/sdfsdf/adsd";
int k=0;
int j=0;
char* b=NULL;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    if(b==0)
    {
        b=strchr(address,'/');
    }
    else
    {
        b=strchr(b,'/');
    }
    j=b-address;
    strncpy(store[i],address+k,j-k);
    k=j;
}
```

But I see that in the code `strncpy(store[i],address+k,j-k)` there's an error. The compiler doesn't seem to understand that `store[i]` is a char pointer, it rather thinks it is a char. Could you see how I can solve the problem?

Thanks for all the help. I've solved it. Solution code is as below:

```
char* address="/a/asdasd/c/sdfsdf/adsd/asfsd";

     char store[5][100];
     char* b=NULL;
     int k=0;
     int j=0;
     for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
     {
         if(b==0)
         {
             b=strchr(address+1,'/');
         }
         else
         {
             b=strchr(b+1,'/');
         }
         j=strlen(address)-strlen(b);
         strncpy(store[i],address+k+1,j-k-1);
         store[i][j-k-1]='\0';
         printf("%s\n",store[i],j-k);
         k=j;
     }
```

Comment: should there be a `int b = 0;` somewhere? what about `a`? `store`?

Comment: No, there should have been char* b=NULL. I edited it. Thanks.

Comment: There are still two more undeclared variables ..

Comment: Your code block should really stand on its own, it's not a good idea to have part of your declarations hidden inside the text of your question. I edited your code to add those missing declarations. Just a suggestion - otherwise it makes it hard to compile/run your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char *store[5]
```

This is just an array of char pointers. To store strings in each element of this array, you need malloc memory and assign it to the respective pointer.

For Ex, you can change your code to

```
store[i] = malloc ((j-k)+ 1); // +1 is for the null terminator. Pls check return value of malloc also.
strncpy(store[i],address+k,j-k);
```

Comment: I knew about using malloc, but I wanted to avoid it because this code is going to be used for project where we don't to use malloc because of memory issues. Isn't there any other way to solve it?

Comment: Can you make it a fixed array like char store[5][100]? and in strncpy, pass the third parameter as (100-1) = 99?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy a pointer, you shouldn't be calling `strncpy()`, since that copies characters.

You want:

```
store[i] = address + (j - k);
```

assuming `address + (j - k)` is the desired starting point for the part.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have a copy of the string tokens, if you like only to retain the pointers,  then just store the address in store[i] as @unwind pointed out.  Or else, you could explore strtok () also. only think is that you need to have separate array to keep each length of the string according to your code. Hope this helps.